# error logging in with user with different role to admin

Tags: laravel, api

I have a api rest made in laravel 5.6 where I authenticate and register with passport and oauth, I register successfully but I am having problems to login with users who do not have an administrator role, he tells me that they are not authorized.

In the front I have no problems, I verify and if the login, email and password data are sent, even pass the validation, the problem is that in my login function:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{   
$credentials = [
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => $request->password
];

if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
    $token = auth()->user()->createToken('TutsForWeb')->accessToken;
    return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
} else {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorised'], 401);
}
}
```

When the user has a role other than admin, the auth () -> attempt ($ credentials) statement becomes null and that is why I get error 401, I do not understand why, when logging in with a user with administrator role if it works correctly.

Comment: Wecome to SO. what difference does the role make in this? you are checking this role somewhere?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I've verified and the role is not important, I just can not log in with any user that I created from an administrator user account, but when I created it from postman i can login.

Comment: Check if your passwords are Hashed Properly.